# json invalid due to quotes in result

Tags: php, html, json

```
$result[] = array('text'=>$text);
echo json_encode($result);
```

my $text contains `""` in the result, so it break my json. I tried `addslashes($text)` but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure the problem is the `""`in the `$text`? json_encode automatically escapes them.

Comment: @oscargilfc I also not sure, take a look at my result http://pastebin.com/n65NAhd4 the source coming from https://www.reddit.com/

Comment: Can you post the $text before encoding?

Comment: @oscargilfc here http://pastebin.com/eZWMeepT

Comment: I guess you are using PHP 5.1.6 or lower, I've just tried and it works, I read PHP 5.1.6 and lower had problems with json_encode and double quotes. But in that case it should work with addslashes...

Comment: @oscargilfc my version is 5.5

Answer (score 0):

If you change `$array` to `$result`, json will escape your `""` without problem :)

```
$text = 'fghgdk"dh"dgf';
$result[]= array('text'=>$text);
echo json_encode($result); // [{"text":"fghgdk\"dh\"dgf"}]
```

Comment: weird in my case the quote is there and didn't escape like yours

Comment: I echo json_encode($result) and this is how it look like  http://pastebin.com/n65NAhd4'

Comment: This paste has been removed!

Comment: @EltonJamie When you convert `&quot;` to quotes ?

Comment: i didn't, could it be my php version problem?

Comment: To check vesrsion, take one string of them, put in variable, and `var_dump($str); echo json_encode($str);` output will give us the answer